Why is there no ".BackColor" when using a ListItem.ListSubitems(i)?
i am currently working on a display in form of a Listview. When trying to assign a color to the background i get a run time error 438.
When i looked into the properties and members i found a ForeColor, which works, but no BackColor.
Why is there no BackColor?
Is there another way to assign a Backcolor?
Public Sub Initialize_Listview()

    Dim Li As ListItem
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    Initialize_Positions
    Initialize_UserForm_Design "List"
    FindAmountValue = RawMaterialShelf_Position_Settings_System.Offset(FindAmount, 0).Value

    List_UserForm.MainList.View = lvwReport
    List_UserForm.MainList.Gridlines = True
    List_UserForm.MainList.HideColumnHeaders = False
    List_UserForm.MainList.FullRowSelect = True

    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Substance).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Substance).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Amount).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Amount).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Floor).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Floor).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Primary).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Primary).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Expired).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Expired).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Reserved).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Reserved).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Reserved_User).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Reserved_User).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Rebought).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Rebought).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Rebought_User).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Rebought_User).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, MHD).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, MHD).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, SubstanceType).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, SubstanceType).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Material).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Material).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, OG_Amount).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, OG_Amount).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, FirstDate).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, FirstDate).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, LastDate).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, LastDate).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, ChangeType).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, ChangeType).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, ChangeName).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, ChangeName).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, ChangeAmount).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, ChangeAmount).ColumnWidth
    List_UserForm.MainList.ColumnHeaders.Add , , RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Bundle_ID).Formula, RawMaterialShelf_Position_Interface.Offset(0, Bundle_ID).ColumnWidth

    List_UserForm.MainList.Font.Name = RawMaterialShelf_Position_Settings_System.Offset(List_FontStyle, 0).Value
    List_UserForm.MainList.Font.Size = RawMaterialShelf_Position_Settings_System.Offset(List_FontSize, 0).Value
    For i = 0 To FindAmountValue
        Set Li = List_UserForm.MainList.ListItems.Add(, , " ")
        For j = 0 To Bundle_ID
            Li.ListSubItems.Add , , " "
            If j >= FirstDate Then
Error here-->       Li.ListSubItems(j + 1).BackColor = RawMaterialShelf_Position_Settings_System.Offset(List_System, 0).Value
                    Li.ListSubItems(j + 1).ForeColor = RawMaterialShelf_Position_Settings_System.Offset(List_Font_System, 0).Value
                Else
Error here-->       Li.ListSubItems(j + 1).BackColor = RawMaterialShelf_Position_Settings_System.Offset(List_Standard, 0).Value
                    Li.ListSubItems(j + 1).ForeColor = RawMaterialShelf_Position_Settings_System.Offset(List_Font_Standard, 0).Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
    EmptyRow = 0
    List_UserForm.Show

End Sub

Everything up to the point of the Error works fine.

Why do you tagged it with VBA?

Because i have the Listview "MainList" in Excel, which uses VBA
